# Haproxy SSL offloading

Tags: ssl, haproxy

I want to load balance 2 apache/php servers with haproxy
Googling around I saw that since version 1.5 dev12, haproxy supports SSL offloading, which as I understand means that there is no need for any extra components in front of haproxy to handle the SSL.

Basically, I followed this article
http://blog.exceliance.fr/2012/09/10/how-to-get-ssl-with-haproxy-getting-rid-of-stunnel-stud-nginx-or-pound/
to setup haproxy

Below my config

```
global
        log 127.0.0.1   local0
        log 127.0.0.1   local1 notice
        #log loghost    local0 info
        maxconn 4096
        chroot /usr/share/haproxy
        uid 99
        gid 99
        daemon
        #debug
        #quiet

defaults
        log     global
        mode    http
        option  httplog
        option  dontlognull
        retries 3
        option  redispatch
        maxconn 2000
        contimeout      5000
        clitimeout      50000
        srvtimeout      50000

frontend ft_test
  mode http
  bind 0.0.0.0:443 ssl crt /home/prx/haproxy_ssl/haproxy.ssl prefer-server-ciphers
  # other (self described) options are: [ciphers <suite>] [nosslv3] [notlsv1]
  default_backend bk_test


backend bk_test
  mode http
  balance roundrobin
  server  inst1 10.1.2.43:80 check inter 2000 fall 3
  server  inst2 10.1.2.142:80 check inter 2000 fall 3
```

The problem is that the backend servers both receive requests at the same time
I mean, I refresh the page once and every time 3 requests appear on the web server's log
A sample of the logs

```
10.1.2.138 - - [24/Jan/2013:12:16:09 -0500] "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 67170
10.1.2.138 - - [24/Jan/2013:12:16:09 -0500] "GET /index.php?=PHPE9568F34-D428-11d2-A769-00AA001ACF42 HTTP/1.1" 200 2524
10.1.2.138 - - [24/Jan/2013:12:16:09 -0500] "GET /index.php?=PHPE9568F35-D428-11d2-A769-00AA001ACF42 HTTP/1.1" 200 2146
```

Sometimes 2 request will hit one server and 1 the other, but 1 page refresh results to 3 requests arriving at the backend
I checked the backend servers configs and they are OK

Is the haproxy config wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Is it possible these requests you see are just multiple HTTP requests to load the page?  I believe the roundrobin balance will have each separate request go to a different backend server.  If you wanted a user to only interact with a single backend server at a time, I think you'd need to look into persistence.  As another possibility, could you be seeing the backend server checks in the logs?

Comment: Hi. I have ruled out all of the above. The page I request is just a phpinfo(). Nothing else. Additionally, the instant I refresh the browser I see the 3 requests, so it cannot be from any checks

Comment: Paul you were right. The phpinfo() was making 3 requests actually. Sometimes your mind gets stuck in the simplest things. Thanks for the help and sorry

Comment: No problem, I'm glad it was an easy one.  I added my comment as an answer if you want to mark it to close this out.

Comment: Thomas, Does your config work for both 80 & 443 I am trying to figure out how to get my Load Balancers to support SSL and nonSSL traffic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible these requests you see are just multiple HTTP requests to load the page? I believe the roundrobin balance will have each separate request go to a different backend server. If you wanted a user to only interact with a single backend server at a time, I think you'd need to look into persistence. As another possibility, could you be seeing the backend server checks in the logs?